# AngularJS directive scope seems to accept only one argument

Tags: javascript, angularjs, yeoman, yeoman-generator-angular

i started learning **AngularJS** and i got stuck on creating my own costume directive.

So, first of all, i'm using **yeoman project** to generate an AngularJS project and this is my starting point.

Now, to the subject -

I have the following code:

**app.js**:

```
myapp.directive('userinfo', function() {
        var directive = {};

        directive.restrict = 'E';
        directive.template = '<b>User: {{ user.firstName }} {{ user.lastName}}</b>';

        directive.scope = {
            user : '='/*, editing: false*/
        };

        return directive;
    });
```

**index.html**:

```
<body ng-app="proj2App" ng-controller="MainCtrl">
...
<userinfo user="users[0]"> </userinfo>
...
</body>
```

**main.js**:

```
angular.module('proj2App')
  .controller('MainCtrl', function ($scope) {
    $scope.users = [
        { firstName : 'John', lastName: 'Doe'}
                     ];
  });
```

My problem as it seems, is found at app.js in the line where i'm defining directive.scope. Whenever it is like that:

```
        directive.scope = {
            user : '='/*, editing: false*/
        };
```

There is no problem and everything works just fine.. But then, when i remove the comment block and it looks like that:

```
        directive.scope = {
            user : '=', editing: false
        };
```

It doesn't work - the page won't show the template and angular will throw the following error which to me absolutely says nothing:

```
**TypeError**: undefined is not a function
    at http://localhost:9000/bower_components/angular/angular.js:6436:30
    at forEach (http://localhost:9000/bower_components/angular/angular.js:331:20)
    at parseIsolateBindings (http://localhost:9000/bower_components/angular/angular.js:6435:5)
    at http://localhost:9000/bower_components/angular/angular.js:6494:49
    at forEach (http://localhost:9000/bower_components/angular/angular.js:323:20)
    at Object.<anonymous> (http://localhost:9000/bower_components/angular/angular.js:6480:13)
    at Object.invoke (http://localhost:9000/bower_components/angular/angular.js:4182:17)
    at Object.enforcedReturnValue [as $get] (http://localhost:9000/bower_components/angular/angular.js:4035:37)
    at Object.invoke (http://localhost:9000/bower_components/angular/angular.js:4182:17)
    at http://localhost:9000/bower_components/angular/angular.js:4000:37
```

Does someone know what is happening here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Set the `editing` variable in the `link` function

```
myapp.directive('userinfo', function () {
    var directive = {};

    directive.restrict = 'E';
    directive.template = '<b>User: {{ user.firstName }} {{ user.lastName}}</b>';

    directive.scope = {
        user: '='
    };

    directive.link = function (scope) {
        scope.editing = false;
    };

    return directive;
});
```

Comment: Thank you, worked great! any reason why doesn't it work the other way?

Comment: Isolated scopes are used to bind data to the scope inside a directive. E.g. binding data from a Controller. But if no data binding is needed and the variable is need in the directives scope, then you just need to declare on the scope in the link function. Hope that helps

Comment: Helps indeed. Thank you :)